# JavaScript SCROLLING in MVC PHP Software without default scroll-behavior smooth - hard direct juming like scroll-behaviour "auto" not working

Tags: javascript, scroll

Hallo dear Community,

It`s a JavaScript issue.
I am trying to program an adequate JavaScript scrolling function for a more complex Widget-System - for a Software.

Framework: MVC Pattern, CI4

I need hard and direct juming to the "next" widgets, after clicking on a "+" button. Instead of that, I get a default scroll-behaviour "smooth" without typing it inside the JavaScript - from the top of the View file:

---

*Lets say... 500 as incoming value:*

```
<body onload="scrollWin(0,500)">
```

**Script inside the View body:**

```
<script>
   function scrollWin(x, y){
       window.scrollTo(x, y);
   }
</script>
```

**RESULT:**
Default scrolling with scroll-behavoiur "smooth", from the top of the View file starting, scrolling all the way down.

---

Does anybody know how to let run this Views getting straight the positions of the widgets without scrolling smooth from the top of the View file?

I tried scrollBy but it didn`t worked.

Glad and thankful for any help, to let run this Application with nice position-scroll "auto"!

Thanks for reading.

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked your CSS? Smooth scrolling behavior could have been activated globally with CSS.

.module {
scroll-behavior: [ auto | smooth ];
}

More on this link https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scroll-behavior/

Comment: Thanks! That's it. The scroll-behavior was activated globally inside a CSS Template file, which was responsible for all HTML elements. It`s thankfully so simple. I just replaced in there the "smooth" attribute with "auto". Now it all works brilliant! Nice.